# Update users in AD in specific OU with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012, ou

Let's say I have below OU tree:

```
DataManagement
└─Country
  ├─Germany
  │ └─Users
  │   ├─Laptops
  │   └─Computers
  ├─France
  │ └─Users
  │   ├─Laptops
  │   └─Computers
  etc.
```

I would like to update specific container in OU, for example, users in laptops group in France. How to do that if I would like to import users from CSV? Below code check and update all OU. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to select a specific container. Any suggestions?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Userscsv = Import-Csv D:\areile\Desktop\adtest.csv

foreach ($User in $Userscsv) {
    Set-ADUser $User.SamAccountName -Replace @{
        Division = $User.Division;
        Office   = $User.Office;
        City     = $User.City
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to update the users _only_ if they are in the France/Users/Laptops OU?

Comment: Exactly! I tried to google the solution but I could not find any value answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it would have helped if you have shown us (part) of the content of the csv then.

However, i think this will work for you:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$UsersCsv = Import-Csv D:\areile\Desktop\adtest.csv

$SearchBase = "<DISTINGHUISHEDNAME-OF-THE-FRENCH-USERS-OU>"

foreach ($usr in $UsersCsv) {
    $adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAdress -eq '$($usr.Email)'} -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties Division,Office,City,EmailAddress
    if ($null -ne $adUser) {
        Set-ADUser $adUser.SamAccountName -Replace @{Division = $usr.Division; Office = $usr.Office; City = $usr.City}
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my csv, file - Name,Surname,Phone,Email,
name1,surnam1,+42222222222,mail@test.loc

Comment: And this is an arror while i tried to compile this -> Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'Name -eq name1' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '10'.
At C:\test\PhoneReplace1.ps1:9 char:15
+     $adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq $($usr.Name)"-SearchBase $SearchBase  ...
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingExc

Comment: That's because the field in your CSV appears to be named `name1`, not `name` as you stated earlier. Anyway, i see you also have a field `Email` in there and that might be even better to use: `Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAdress-eq '$($usr.Email)'" -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties Division,Office,City`

Comment: I have just edited my answer to use the EmailAddress wich is a value in your csv called `mail`

Comment: I just edit it to my use and - Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users =  Import-Csv 'C:\test\testfile.csv' 
$users
$SearchBase = "OU=Deployment,OU=Poland,OU=Users,OU=Laptop,DC=test,DC=loc"
$SearchBase

#add mobile phone to unique users
foreach($usr in $users){
    $adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAdress -eq '$($usr.Email)'" -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties FirstName, LastName, MobilePhone,EmailAddress
    if ($null -ne $adUser) {
     Set-ADUser $adUser.SamAccountName -Replace @{MobilePhone = $usr.MobilePhone}
    }
}

Comment: this is csv - EmailAddress,FirstName,LastName,MobilePhone
wkostrzewski@test.loc,Wiktor,Kostrzewski,123-555-1211

Comment: An error look like this -> Get-ADUser : One or more properties are invalid.
Parameter name: FirstName
At C:\test\PhoneReplace1.ps1:9 char:15
+     $adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAdress -eq '$($usr.Email)'" -SearchBase $ ...

Comment: the quotes were a typo. use `{EmailAdress -eq '$($usr.Email)'}`. BUT... How come now the field in the csv is suddenly called `EmailAddress` when first it was called `Email` ?? PLease give the correct field headers in the csv otherwise it will never work.

Comment: Ok i changed the csv to basic data now -> Email,LastName
wkostrzewski@test.loc, Kostrzewski but error is like this -> Email                                                              ADUser : Directory object not found
At C:\test\PhoneReplace1.ps1:9 char:15
+     $adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAdress -eq '$($usr.Email)'} -SearchBase $ ...

Comment: and code is like this -> foreach ($usr in $users) {
    $adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAdress -eq '$($usr.Email)'} -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties EmailAddress,Surname
    if ($null -ne $adUser) {
        Set-ADUser $adUser.SamAccountName -Replace @{EmailAddress = $usr.Email; Surname = $usr.LastName;}
    }
}

Comment: I am using powershell v 4

Comment: so what do you get when you simply type `Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAdress -eq 'wkostrzewski@test.loc'}`

Comment: I found that removing  -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties Division,Office,City,EmailAddress this piece of code allows program to run (without updating mobile entry)

Comment: Check your searchbase. The user you are trying to update is nog in the OU specified

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the `SamAccountName` to identify the user, you can retrieve the user account object using `Get-ADUser` and inspect the `DistinguishedName` attribute before calling `Set-ADUser`:

```
$BaseOU = 'OU=Laptops,OU=Users,OU=France,DC=domain,DC=tld'

ForEach ($User in $Userscsv)
{
    Get-ADUser $User.sAMAccountName |Where-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -like "*,$BaseOU"} |Set-ADUser -Replace @{
        Division = $User.Division; 
        Office = $User.Office; 
        City = $User.City
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, CSV have  only name, surname and phone number and i would like to update phone number